# Unblock "less" after follow mode / scrolling past end of buffer

Tags: pipe, less, tail, buffer

I'm using `less` to capture the output of a live program. Using `F` activates follow mode, showing me real-time output. However, after entering follow mode (or, more generally, scrolling past the buffered output, with `G`, for example), I'm not able to control `less` anymore.

`Ctrl-c` kind of works here, but unfortunately it kills the other program.

Is there a way to regain control of `less` after scrolling past the buffer?

Comment: As a workaround: why don't you redirect to a file instead of piping to less? Then you could use less on the file in another terminal. btw the OS and shell you are using may be helpful in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Simple case

In my Debian 9, if I run `less` to read a regular file, e.g.:

```
less /etc/fstab
```

and then pass `F` (i.e. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) then I will see

```
Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)
```

This indicates an interrupt is by design the right way to "undo" `F`. Indeed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does this.

---

#### Your case

> I'm using `less` to capture the output of a live program.

I'm guessing it's like this:

```
program1 | less
# or
program1 | program2 | … | less
```

Now the problem arises (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kills the other program) because the following happens:

0. The shell places every part of the pipeline (i.e. `less` and every `programN`) in a process group with PGID (process group ID) equal to the PID (process ID) of the first command (i.e. `program1`).
1. The shell notifies the terminal this PGID is now the foreground process group.
2. When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the terminal sends `SIGINT` to the foreground process group.
3. In effect `less` *and* every `programN` receive `SIGINT`.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165715/108618) and [this blog entry](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=34). A remotely related interesting case is in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1260918/432690).

Some really basic shells (e.g. `posh`) may run *everything* in the process group of the shell itself. This does not affect the problem (`less` *and* every `programN` receive `SIGINT`), but can invalidate some solutions. Your shell is most likely "sophisticated enough". In my Debian even `sh` from `busybox` is sophisticated enough.

---

#### Solutions

You want `less` and `less` only to receive `SIGINT`. Possibilities:

0. Send `SIGINT` only to `less`:

   ```
    kill -s SIGINT $pid_of_less
   ```

where `$pid_of_less` denotes PID of the right `less` process (you need to find it somehow). If you're sure the right `less` is the only `less` you are allowed to signal or if you don't mind signalling other `less` processes then this is the simplest way:

```
    killall -s SIGINT less
```

**This solution should always work.** It does not require you to modify the pipeline beforehand.

You can run `kill` (or `killall`) in a separate shell (separate console) or (if your shell allows this) suspend the pipeline with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, run whatever you need and finally bring the pipeline back to the foreground with `fg`.

0. Make everything but `less` immune to `SIGINT`. Few possibilities:

   ```
    sh -c 'trap "" SIGINT; program1' | less
    sh -c 'trap "" SIGINT; exec program1' | less
    sh -c 'trap "" SIGINT; program1 | program2 | …' | less

    ( trap "" SIGINT; program1 ) | less
    ( trap "" SIGINT; exec program1 ) | less
    ( trap "" SIGINT; program1 | program2 | … ) | less
   ```

Notes and quirks:

- Examples with `sh -c …` require additional level of quoting. They may be inconvenient if there are quotes in your original line. If there's anything that should be expanded in the main shell then single-quotes cannot embrace it ([the outer quotes matter](https://superuser.com/a/1404245/432690)). It may get complicated.
- Examples with `sh -c …` require syntax compatible with `sh`. If your original line uses syntax or tools (like builtins) that `sh` cannot understand, then you should consider other possibilities.
- Examples with subshells (`( … )`) use whatever shell you use. It will most likely understand `trap "" SIGINT` and work as desired, but in general it may not.
- Each `programN` on its own can register a handler for `SIGINT`. Note `less` does it, so we can even start it from a shell with `SIGINT` ignored:

  ```
       ( trap "" SIGINT; program1 | less )
       # similarly with other examples
  ```

  and it will still be able to react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. But if another program makes itself vulnerable again then it will defeat the purpose.
- Any `programN` may not terminate when you exit `less`. It may be because

  - it doesn't know yet the pipe it writes to is closed, because it hasn't tried to write anything since the pipe was closed, so `SIGPIPE` has not been generated yet (it's normal, compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1405010/432690));
  - or by design it doesn't exit on `SIGPIPE`;
  - or it's a loop which runs command(s) that do exit on `SIGPIPE`, but the loop doesn't care and runs them again and again.

  In such case the easiest way to recover would be to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but obviously if you make `programN` immune to `SIGINT` then this will not work for it. You will need to kill it with `SIGTERM` or another signal. Note just killing the subshell or the additional `sh` shell will not kill its children. Signalling the entire process group of the (sub)shell is a good way, like this:

  ```
       kill -- -$pgid
  ```

  where `$pgid` denotes the right process group ID (and `-` just before tells `kill` to target a group, not just one process). `$pgid` will be the PID of the (sub)shell, if the subshell was first in the pipe.

  You don't need to know any ID if job control is enabled in your interactive shell. E.g. in Bash hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then `kill %+`. This should kill the entire job.

0. Place everything but `less` outside of the foreground process group.
1. With `setsid`:

   ```
       setsid -w program1 | less
       # or
       setsid -w sh -c 'program1 | program2 | …' | less
   ```

   As before, any `programN` may not terminate when `less` exits. As before, if this happens, you will need to kill it with a signal. The difference is this time `SIGINT` can be the signal. On the other hand the trick with `kill %-` will not work.
2. With process substitution, if your shell supports it. I will elaborate for Bash.

   ```
       # in Bash
       less -f <(program1)
       # or
       less -f <(program1 | program2 | …)
   ```

   And again any `programN` may not terminate when you exit `less`, unfortunately. But note anything in `<( )` starts in the process group of the original shell, so you can send `SIGINT` to it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as soon as the shell registers its own process group as the foreground group again. In a script this could be a problem, but in an interactive shell it's enough to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when you get the prompt after `less` exits. Yes, in this case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will send `SIGINT` to some processes that seem to work in the background (but they belong to the current foreground process group, so formally they are in the foreground).

   You can automate this: `kill 0` will signal its own process group, so it's enough to run `kill` in the process group of the shell and this is very easy. Like this:

   ```
       # in Bash
       less -f <(program1); kill -s SIGINT 0
       # or
       less -f <(program1 | program2 | …); kill -s SIGINT 0
   ```

   **The above solution is quite elegant.** Remember `kill` here is only to signal programs that would otherwise remain. If your programs exit by themselves anyway then you may not run `kill` at all. On the other hand if there are *other* programs in the process group of the shell (e.g. you did `exec 3< <(whatever)`) then `kill 0` will signal them as well.

   <sup>Note about Zsh: my tests indicate that in Zsh you can use `less -f <( … )` and prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from sending `SIGINT` to programs, just like in Bash; but Zsh will run them in *yet another* process group (not the process group of the shell), so the trick with `kill 0` will not work.</sup>

   Also note this will *not* work:

   ```
       # not a solution
       less < <(program1)
       # or
       less < <(program1 | program2 | …)
   ```

   because this time everything inside `<( )` will formally descend from `less` and share its process group, which will be the foreground process group, which will receive `SIGINT` upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This formal descendance from `less` happens because `less` originally starts as a subshell which sets redirections for itself and only then replaces itself with `less` (this is a normal way for shells to run programs). So in the process tree it will appear `less` spawned a shell which spawned `program1` etc. (compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1546275/432690) where `sshd` *allegedly* spawned `sleep`).

   And while in this case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> can reach each `programN`, any `programN` may still not terminate when you exit `less` without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Then the trick with `kill 0` will not work. Totally not a solution.
3. With separate invocations.

   Invoke `less` separately in a way so it's the only command in the foreground process group and no other process will receive `SIGINT` upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. You need a named pipe or a regular file to pass data from `program1 …` to `less`.

   0. Create a file:

      ```
          mkfifo myfile    # of the type named fifo
          # or
          : > myfile       # of the type regular file
      ```
   1. Run `program1 …` and let it write to the file

   - either in a separate shell, separate terminal (not the one where you're going to run `less`):

     ```
             program1 … >> myfile
     ```
   - or in the background in a terminal where you're going to run `less` (note this is not a valid solution for shells that run *everything* in the process group of the shell itself – really basic shells, remember?):

     ```
             program1 … >> myfile &
     ```

     I used `>>`, not `>`. For a fifo it doesn't matter. For a regular file it allows you to truncate the file later without issues (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1342490/432690)).

   0. Run `less`:

      ```
          less -f myfile
          # or
          less < myfile
      ```

      <sup>(`-f` not needed in case of a regular file).</sup>

      Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in this terminal will only affect `less`.
   1. If you exit `less` and the rest is still running, and you want it to stop, then

   - if it runs in the separate terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> there;
   - if it runs in the background in the same terminal:
     - `fg`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
     - or `kill -s SIGINT %+`, if supported (specify different signal if needed),
     - or `kill -s SIGINT -- -"$!"` (specify different signal if needed).

   0. Remove the file:

      ```
          rm myfile
      ```

---

#### Notes

- Running `program1` in the background or inside `<( )` will detach its stdin from the terminal. If it was going to be a problem, you would have experienced issues when `less` and the program tried to read from the terminal simultaneously. You reported no issues (or had already taken care and detached `program1` from the terminal), so apparently the program doesn't read from the terminal. Therefore running in the background or inside `<( )` should not break anything.
- In my tests `less`, after successfully "undoing" `F` without killing anything (per any solution), eventually stops reading data. This blocks the rest of the pipe (usually; the writing `programN` may be designed not to wait, it may exit or whatever). This is rather expected, I'm mentioning this for the sake of less experienced users. To unblock I need to pass `F` again. But if I use a regular file as an interface between `programN` and `less` then the program will not block because of `less` (the filesystem may get full though).